# date_format function in Hive gives wrong result

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to convert a string to a date with microseconds using the command date_format

query:

```
select date_format('2021-04-14 16:07:47.123456', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS')
```

result:

```
2021-04-14 16:07:47.000123
```

`try hive.parquet.write.int64.timestamp=true` and `hive.parquet.timestamp.time.unit` - don't work

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to convert a string to a date with microseconds using the command date_format

Try this sql query:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(cast('2021-04-14 16:07:47.123456' as TIMESTAMP), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS')
```